# Enable VAT Field during checkout in Magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2, input-field

i am struggling to find how to enable the VAT field in Magento 2.
I am not talking about Tax Rules or percentages, i am just not able to display the input field related to VAT during checkout.

If i remember well in Magento 1.* it was enabled by default.

Also is there a fast way to enable the vat field, just in the case someone enter some text in the "Company Name" field?

Thank you very much to whoever will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to enable the field you just need to set "Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Show VAT Number at Frontend" to "Yes".